# $n^i$, $n^{a+bi}$, $\sqrt[i]{n}$, and $\sqrt[a+bi]{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, complex-numbers

This might seem like a basic question for a lot of people, but I'm just a fan of playing with maths and don't study it seriously. Recently, I posted a question asking for values of $n$ in the formula
$$f(x)=\sqrt[n]{100}^{n-1}*\sqrt[n]{x}$$
that would not return the forumla in that format. For example, consider $\phi$ (the Golden Ratio) which returns
$$f(x)=\sqrt[\phi^2]{100}*\sqrt[\phi]{x}$$

Included in that, I was wondering if there if were possible that $n\in\mathbb{C}$ where $\mathbb{C}$ is represented by $a+bi$ and $b\neq0$. Obviously, there are an infinite number of values that fit that requirement, but I'm narrowing the search by requesting that $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$.

For that reason, I wanted to toy around with some of the properties of $i$ but, sadly, my maths education stopped at AB Calc (which I didn't do too well in), so I don't know the following properties. I tried looking online but I got a bit confused. I was hoping somebody might be able to explain what happens in the following situations so that I can continue my exploration of $f(x)$:

1. $n^i$ — based on what I've read, it looks like $n^i=cos(1)i=0i=i$, but I'm not sure that's right.
2. $n^{a+bi}$ — based on what I've read, it looks like $n^i=sin(a)+cos(b)i$, but I'm not sure that's right.
3. $\sqrt[i]{n}$ — I assume this is related to (1) in that it would have a similar rule just playing out in the denominator of the exponent, but I'm not super familiar with $i$ or its properties outside of AB calc (and that's *rusty*).
4. $\sqrt[a+bi]{n}$ — I would assume this is related to (2) in that it would have a similar rule just playing out in the denominator of the exponent, but I'm not sure at *all* on that one.

Again, I know this might be a 'basic' question for some of you, but I'm not well-versed enough in maths to go read a mathematical proof and fully understand it and the materials I've already found were pretty confusing. Can somebody please meet me where I'm at and explain it slowly (maybe even with a written proof to accompany the maths with the property names)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, I gave the example of $\phi$ in the way. Normally, it would return $$f(x)=\sqrt[\phi]{100}^{\phi-1}*\sqrt[\phi]{x}$$. Instead, because of the property that $$\phi-1=\frac{1}{\phi}$$, it could be restructured as the formula in the question: $$f(x)=\sqrt[\phi^2]{100}*\sqrt[\phi]{x}$$

Comment: I suppose I mean 'it could be rendered as', 'it could be reärranged as', or 'it would have the alternative form as'. Continuing with the example: $$f(x)=\sqrt[\phi]{100}^{\phi-1}*\sqrt[\phi]{x}=\sqrt[\phi^2]{100}*\sqrt[\phi]{x}$$

Comment: No, that was the pretext for what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a value  $n\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{C}=a+bi, i=\sqrt{-1}, b\neq0$ and $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}$. To do that, I need to understand the rules for $n^\mathbb{C}$ and $n^\frac{1}{\mathbb{C}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for a simple rule that does not exist. First of all, all the cases that you wish to look at can be handled by $n^{a+bi}$ because $1/(a+bi)=(a-bi)/(a^2+b^2)$. Now the answer you seek can be expressed as

$$
n^{a+bi}=n^a n^{ib}=
n^a e^{\ln(n^{ib})}=n^ae^{ib\ln n}=n^a\big(\cos(b\ln n)+i\sin(b\ln n)\big)
$$

Thus,

$$n^i=\cos(\ln n)+i\sin(\ln n)$$

And so forth. You can verify the above numerically if you like.

In polar coordinates we have similarly,

$$n^{re^{i\theta}}=e^{\ln(n^{re^{i\theta}})}=e^{r\ln n (\cos\theta +i\sin \theta)}=e^{r\ln n \cos\theta}\big(\cos(r\ln n \sin\theta)+i\sin(r\ln n \sin\theta)\big)$$